# Stop an application through terminal

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu and i would like to stop a running application from terminal, more precisely through a script. One way is to get the pid of the process and issue a kill command with the pid of the process. But how do i get the pid of running applications? Or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Probably better asked on the [Ubuntu site](http://askubuntu.com/), or [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 24):

you can use

> ps -ax | grep application name
>   if your searching for firefox type below command

```
ps -ax | grep firefox
```

it shows the processing id of corresponding applications you can stop that application by kill command if process id=1317,

```
kill -9 1317
```

Answer (score 6):

How to stop an application from opening at start?

You will have to type `ps -A` and Enter.

After that you will get a list of every app that that is starting by itself.

```
kill -9  (the number of the app)
```

Send me a message it that does not help you.

Comment: this is godd it helps me :)

Answer (score 4):

If you know the name of the application:

```
$ pidof "name of application" (This will return the pid of that application)  
$ kill -9 "pid"
```

Here is a basic bash script I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
PID=`pidof start_program`
kill $PID
```

"start_program" is the name of the application running.

Answer (score 3):

ps -ef | grep application name

Answer (score 1):

[pkill](http://man.cx/pkill) will probably cover your use case.

Answer (score 0):

> Or is there any better way to do this?

Depends on the application.  Some applications write their PID to a file.